# How to restructure JSON to be rendered on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, axios

I'm having trouble displaying nested JSON data on my web site, even though it's logging the data just fine on the console.
I'm using ReactJS, and Axios for my API call.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import configData from "./configData.json";
import axios from 'axios'



export default function App() {
  const [news, setNews] = React.useState([]);

  async function fetchNews() {
    const newsGetEndpoint = configData.GET_MEDICAL_NEWS;

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(newsGetEndpoint);
      setNews(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    fetchNews()
  }, [])

return (
<div>
    {news.Items?.length > 0 ? (
      <div>
        {news.Items.map((new, id) => {
          const values = new[0];
          return (
            <div key={id}>Name: <span>{values.Company_Name}</span></div>
          )
        }
        )}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>No News from API</div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

The response that gets returned from the API looks like this when I console-log it:

```json
{ 
  "Count": 5, 
  "Items": [ 
    { 
      "id": { 
        "S": "9d748c4c04a6b6db3e22a849f372a6616866d1377a4b213bc36f019f2dce6060"
      }, 
      "news_values": { 
        "S": "[{\"Company Name\": \"New York Times\", \"isAudited\": false}, {\"Date of Service\": \"2/20/2022\", \"isAudited\": false}, {\"Location Name\": \"New York\", \"isAudited\": false}
      ...
```

I mainly want to display what is under news_values as three columns: (1)Company Name, (2)Date of Service, (3) Location Name.

The current behaviour is the web site doesn't even show up, and in the console, the error said:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Company_Name')"

What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not match the structure of your data in a few ways.

First the default data for the `news` state variable should be `{}` or `{Items: []}`, not `[]`. Next the value of `new` (map iteration instance variable from `news.Items` is an object, not an array so you shouldn't call `const values = new[0]`, I think what you meant was to get the first element of `new.news_values.S`.

However, the value of `new.news_values.S` is a JSON string, not an object or array so you will need to handle that. If possible, I would update the server to return an array or object rather than a JSON string. Otherwise you can parse the string and use the following line:

```
const values = JSON.parse(new.news_values.S)[0];
```

Then you can access properties with `values["Company Name"]` (note that the key is `"Company Name"`, not `"Company_Name"`).

If you want all of the elements of `new.news_values.S` you can add another `.map` call and just use `const values = JSON.parse(new.news_values.S)` (without the `[0]` at the end).

Comment: Hi, i changed the state of news to {} per what you said. I also updated it to const values = JSON.parse(new.news_values.S)[0]; I also tried to render it by doing {values["Company Name"]}. It's still not working. Do you have some advice by chance?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so what does it say?

Comment: The error says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'S')". I also put a console.log("values", values) underneath the const values = JSON.parse(new.news_values.S)[0]; and it is console-logging the Company Name values as expected. It's just not rendering it on the website, which is just blank for now

Comment: Could be different renders, move the `console.log` call to above the `const values = ...` line.

Comment: When I moved the console.log for values above the const values =... line, it didn't work. The error says "Can not access "i" before initialization", but if I move the console.log back to below the const values=... line, then the console.log works, even though nothing gets rendered as well